# Ideal in projective tensor product of Banach algebras

Tags: tensor-products, banach-algebras

Let $A,B$ be Banach algebras and  $A\hat{\otimes}B$ be  projective tensor product of them.
Let $S$ be an ideal of $A\hat{\otimes}B$. Are there ideals $I$ of $A$ and $J$ of $B$ such that 
$S=I\hat{\otimes}J$?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been though through more carefully, by considering finite-dimensional cases

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you mean closed ideals.  Howver the result is not even true in the simplest non-trivial case, that of two dimensional algebras.  This is most easily seen by dualising it to the obviously false claim that closed subsets of products are products of closed subsets.