# Quotient of a Banach algebra

Tags: banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. Is there a Banach algebra $B$ and a non-trivial closed ideal $I$ of $B$ such that $\frac{B}{I}\cong A$?

Comment: How about $B=A\oplus A$, $I=A\oplus 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Let $K$ be any compact Hausdorff space that contains at least two points and for $B$ take the space of $A$ valued continuous functions on $K$. Take any $p$ in $K$. Let $I$ be the ideal of all functions in $B$ that vanish at $p$.

Comment: Bill, I really don't think one should encourage questions like this on MO. Cf. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217749/ideal-in-projective-tensor-product-of-banach-algebras

Comment: You are right, Yemon.  Sorry.